# Return numpy array of unspecified size in SWIG

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

My goal is to use SWIG with C and Python to create a function that takes a NumPy array as input and returns a different NumPy array.  The returned array is of some unspecified size that depends on the input array. Unfortunately when I try to run my code I get an empty array returned. Here is a "minimal" example that shows the problem.  I run this code via:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python test.py
```

The files of interest are copied below. Please let me know if you know how to make this code return a nonempty NumPy array.  Thanks!

cancelterms.c:

```
#include "cancelterms.h"
void cancel(double complex* vec, int m, int n, double complex sum[])
{   

    // Some code that processes vec.

    // This is just an example. In practice the following lines will depend on vec.
    sum[0] = 1.0;
    sum[1] = 2.5;
    sum[2] = 3.6;
}
```

cancelterms.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

void cancel(double complex* vec, int m, int n, double complex sum[]);
```

cancelterms.i:

```
%module cancelterms
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "cancelterms.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%include <complex.i>

%numpy_typemaps(double complex, NPY_CDOUBLE, int)

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%apply (double complex* INPLACE_ARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(double complex* vec, int m, int n)}
%apply (double complex ARGOUT_ARRAY1[ANY]) {(double complex sum[])}

%include "cancelterms.h"
```

setup.py:

```
# Import necessary modules.
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy as np

try:
    numpy_include = np.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    numpy_include = np.get_numpy_include()

example_module = Extension('_cancelterms', sources=['cancelterms.c', 'cancelterms.i'], include_dirs = [numpy_include])

setup(name='cancelterms', ext_modules=[example_module], py_modules=["cancelterms"])
```

test.py:

```
import cancelterms
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1.0j,2.0j,3.0j,4.0j,5.0j,6.0j],[-1.0j,-2.0j,-3.0j,6.0j,7.0j,8.0j]])
print cancelterms.cancel(a)
```

Unfortunately numpy.i is too large to paste here, but I use the standard numpy.i file from the numpy github repository with the small modification that I add double complex to the list of types.

Answer (score 1):

The `...[ANY]` typemaps are for arrays with **hard-coded dimensions**. This is stated clearly in the [numpy.i docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html#input-arrays) for input arrays, but applies to the others as well.

For instance, they could be used as:

```
%apply (double complex ARGOUT_ARRAY1[ANY]) {(double complex sum[5])}
```

if your function took an array of size 5 (allocated by the caller / in the wrapper code).

The point is that SWIG has no way of knowing what size the argout array `sum` will be. It is pure coincidence that your code compiles and runs at all. Have a look at the generated wrapper code (search for 'wrap_cancel'), and you will see what is going on.

There are also the following typemaps:

- `( DATA_TYPE* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1 )`
  where you can specify the size of the array to be pre-allocated
- `( DATA_TYPE** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, DIM_TYPE* DIM1 )`
  where the array is allocated by the function, but additionally the size of the allocated array is returned.

In your case the function `cancel` allocates the memory for the array `sum`, assuming the caller has some way of figuring out the size. There are no predefined typemaps for this case.

This is similar to the case where the function just returns a `double complex *`, and as stated in the docs for numpy.i:

> If you run into a situation where a function or method is returning a pointer to an array, your best bet is to write your own version of the function to be wrapped, either with %extend for the case of class methods or %ignore and %rename for the case of functions.